# Swagger error: Relative paths to the individual endpoints

Tags: node.js, swagger

Using node `v7.10.0` and npm `4.2.0`.

I have created a nodejs 'Hello World' project and I was trying to reorganize the `swagger.yaml` taking the paths out of the main yaml file into a sepparate `paths.yaml` file:

This is my `api/swagger/swagger.yaml`:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Hello World App
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:10010
# basePath prefixes all resource paths
basePath: /
#
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  $ref: './paths.yaml'
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions
definitions:
  HelloWorldResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

and this is the `api/swagger/paths.yaml` that I'm referencing to:

```
/hello:
  # binds a127 app logic to a route
  x-swagger-router-controller: hello_world
  get:
    description: Returns 'Hello' to the caller
    # used as the method name of the controller
    operationId: hello
    parameters:
      - name: name
        in: query
        description: The name of the person to whom to say hello
        required: false
        type: string
    responses:
      "200":
        description: Success
        schema:
          # a pointer to a definition
          $ref: "#/definitions/HelloWorldResponse"
      # responses may fall through to errors
      default:
        description: Error
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

I get the following Swagger error:

```
Relative paths to the individual endpoints. They must be relative to the 'basePath'.

Reference could not be resolved: ./paths.yaml
```

Both files 'swagger.yaml' and 'paths.yaml' are placed in the same directory 'api/swagger/'.
I've tried to reference `paths.yaml` in different ways:

```
paths:
  $ref: 'paths.yaml'
```

or

```
paths:
  $ref: './api/swagger/paths.yaml'
```

But I get the same error. Is it possible to reference the paths in a sepparate yaml file?